# Warning pg_execute(): Query failed: ERROR: index row size 2728 exceeds maximum 2717 for index "index_name"

Tags: php, postgresql

New using PHP with PG functions.
Please help.

I am receiving the following *warning*:

> Warning pg_execute(): Query failed: ERROR: index row size 2728 exceeds maximum 2717 for index "index_name".

Not sure what it means.

Code example:

```
$query      = pg_prepare($pgConn, "query", "UPDATE table_name SET field_name=array_cat(field_name, $1) WHERE id=$2;");
$query      = pg_execute($pgConn, "query", array($param1, $param2));
```

I can see that index is not able to be created for that record because of the too big data, but does it mean that the data is also not stored into DB?

Answer (score 1):

If updating the index fails and causes an error, the whole operation fails and is undone. Table and index are always modified together.

Since an index entry has to fit in one 8kB block, and there is some overhead per block, and PostgreSQL requires that at least three index entries fit into one block, you end up with a length limit like 2717 for an index entry.

There are two options:

- drop that index
- if you need the index for equality searches, you could create a "hash index" (`USING hash`); that can index large values, because it only stores a hash